# from django.utils import importlib, six ImportError: cannot import name 'importlib' from 'django.utils'

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using below version

python 3.7.4
Django 2.0.5
MySQL 5.5
restframework 3.0

while running getting error as below, please help me

File "C:\Users\Imbesat Anwar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 22, in 
    from django.utils import importlib, six
ImportError: cannot import name 'importlib' from 'django.utils' (C:\Users\Imbesat Anwar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils__init__.py)

Comment: Try  `import importlib`  as `django.utils.importlib` was deprecated in Django 1.7 and removed in Django 1.9

Comment: Where I have to add this importlib , importlib I am not using anywhere in my application.

Comment: Please guide me if you know how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your `djangorestframework` to 3.1 or higher.